# enable page for user in html

Tags: asp.net, html

I have problem to set the page for one user. 
I have the page A that cannot access for only one user. But only this user can access to pages B. Pages A and B almost have a same content. In page A, any user can add and search but on page B, user can only search. I have done as below code:

```asp
<%if username<>"liza" then%><a href="a.asp" class="white-text"> Delivery Record (Self collect) </a><%end if%>
    <%if username="liza"  then%><a href="b.asp" class="white-text"> Delivery Record (Self collect) </a><%end if%>
```

But the problem now, the user sometimes can see the content from page A, sometimes she cannot. But for other user they only can see page A. Only one user have this problem. Is there something wrong with the code?

For the result, this user only can access to page B not the page A.

Comment: shouldn't be `if username == "liza"` see the 2 x `=` and not only one? As one you are assigning the value, not comparing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two mistakes in your shared code:

1. When comparing a string always use `ToLower()` because word Liza or
   LIZA is not equal to liza.
2. You have used username = "liza" in second code block that incorrect because here you are assigning not comparing.

**Solution**

```
<%if username.ToLower() <> "liza" then%>
    <a href="a.asp" class="white-text"> Delivery Record (Self collect) </a>
<%end if%>

<%if username.ToLower() == "liza"  then%>
    <a href="b.asp" class="white-text"> Delivery Record (Self collect) </a>
<%end if%>
```

Also, you can avoid two conditional `if` case and make them one.

```
<%if username.ToLower() <> "liza" then%>
    <a href="a.asp" class="white-text"> Delivery Record (Self collect) </a>
<%else%>
    <a href="b.asp" class="white-text"> Delivery Record (Self collect) </a>
<%end if%>
```

Comment: Thanks, the second option works for me. I will monitor it for now.